# Prestashop : display a notification on screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, prestashop-1.6

I'm new on Prestashop and i would like to display a notification like bootstrap alert (Success or Danger) after the customer registration.
I tried many solution but in vain.
For example those lines of code does not work:

```
$this->displayWarning($this->l('test'));
$this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('test');
$this->displayInformation('test');
```

any help please !

Comment: Where are you using this code?

Comment: I use this code inside a module main class, actually i work on module

Comment: Then you need to call the right hook. Call the hook which fires after user registration.

Comment: The name of the hook is **actionCustomerAccountAdd** i dont know how to add the notification!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this->context->controller->errors[] = 'test';` to display errors.

For other types (info, warning) you will have to manually assign in your module hook data to smarty.

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('confirmations', 'Confirm text');
```

Then in your `identity.tpl` insert at the top

```
{if isset($confirmations)}
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {$confirmations|escape:'htmlall':'utf-8'}
    </div>
{/if}
```

Repeat the process for warnings, informations etc.